# How to make Outlook search in server (not just locally-cached messages)

Tags: microsoft-outlook

How can I make (PC-installed, not web-based) Outlook search in the actual Exchange server, not just locally-cached messages?

Old messages don't show up in my searches as Outlook is looking only in the local cache, and not the full message database. Messages ARE found if I click the "Click here to view more on Microsoft Exchange" (see snapshot below) on the folders of the local PC to force downloading of old messages, but obviously, I can't do this when searching for messages, since I don't know before hand in which folder they are!

Thanks in advance for any help!

P.S. I do enable the "Search subfolders" option in the Advanced Find dialog window (see snapshot below), and check the top-most folder (or all folders underneath--it doesn't matter, program behavior doesn't change).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my knowledge, this behavior is up to your configuration in your outlook, the below screenshot for your reference:[image]

If your Mail to keep offline setting is set to 12 months and you have email items in your Exchange mailbox that are older than 12 months, those items reside only in your mailbox on the server.

If you want to search all mails stored in exchange database, you could drag the Mail to keep offline slider to the desired number of months or to All to synchronize all email messages.

For more details: [Only a subset of your Exchange mailbox items are synchronized in Outlook](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/user-interface/only-subset-items-synchronized#cause)

Comment: Thanks so much your reply, Joy! Extending/disabling the caching solves the problem. Just one caveat: after making the change, I still need to click on (i.e. open) every mailbox folder to have Outlook "react" and download its messages (otherwise they still don't show up in search results). Do you know if there's any way of forcing Outlook to download all messages for all mailbox folders? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Based on my knowledge, if you choose the All option, you should restart outlook and you should soon see a message informing you that “Your folders are up to date” at the bottom of Outlook. It indicates all messages have been download from exchange server side.